# What is difference between Gulp and Grunt in VS2015?

Tags: gruntjs, visual-studio-2015, gulp, task-runner-explorer

I am new to `Visual Studio 2015`.
Just I came across to know the folder structure and the tools provided to manage `script` file and `css` file using `Task` runners: [Gulp](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html) and [Grunt](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-grunt.html)

I am not able to differentiate between two i.e Gulp and Grunt. Which one to be used one over the other?

Can any one suggest when to use one over the other?